# SQL join of 2 date tables with gaps (Lookup)

Tags: sql, join

***UPDATED***

I have added a example of the dataset so its easier to explain my problem. It looks to me if it is a lookup question.

I have a basetable with all months from 2013-01 to 2014-12. I have a lookuptable with contract working hours per person (column id; e.g. person 1 and person 2).

I have to match the basetable months with the right contracthours for that month. The lookup table provides historical information about changes in workweek hours.

**Can somebody help me to make this join or lookup?**

**Example result person 1** : The contractual hours for april 2013 (2013-04) should be 16 hours. Because in the lookup table he worked 16 hours from 2013-02-18 and started working 8 hours on 2013-04-16.

**Example result person 2** : His last contractual change is of 2012-11-01 to 32 hours. So all months in 2013 & 2014 has to be 32 hours.

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_Lookup](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Hours] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (1, N'2013-01-01 00:00:00', 8)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (1, N'2013-02-18 00:00:00', 16)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (1, N'2013-04-16 00:00:00', 8)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (1, N'2013-05-01 00:00:00', 32)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (1, N'2013-09-15 00:00:00', 12)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (1, N'2013-10-01 00:00:00', 20)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (1, N'2015-01-01 00:00:00', 12)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (2, N'2008-01-01 00:00:00', 24)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (2, N'2009-03-01 00:00:00', 36)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (2, N'2009-08-31 00:00:00', 24)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (2, N'2010-02-01 00:00:00', 36)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (2, N'2010-04-01 00:00:00', 30)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (2, N'2011-08-01 00:00:00', 24)
INSERT [dbo].[_Lookup] ([ID], [Date], [Hours]) VALUES (2, N'2012-11-01 00:00:00', 32)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_Basetable](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A15800000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A17400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A19300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A1B100000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A1D000000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A1EE00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A20D00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A22C00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A24A00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A26900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A28700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A2A600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A2C500000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A2E100000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A30000000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A31E00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A33D00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A35B00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A37A00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A39900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A3B700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A3D600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x0000A3F400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A15800000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A17400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A19300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A1B100000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A1D000000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A1EE00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A20D00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A22C00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A24A00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A26900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A28700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A2A600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A2C500000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[_Basetable] ([ID], [Date]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x0000A2E100000000 AS DateTime))


--  The result table should look like this:
--  
--  
--  ID  Date
--  1   2013-01-01  8
--  1   2013-02-01  8
--  1   2013-03-01  16
--  1   2013-04-01  16
--  1   2013-05-01  32
--  1   2013-06-01  32
--  1   2013-07-01  32
--  1   2013-08-01  32
--  1   2013-09-01  32
--  1   2013-10-01  20
--  1   2013-11-01  20
--  1   2013-12-01  20
--  1   2014-01-01  20  
--  1   2014-02-01  20  
--  1   2014-03-01  20  
--  1   2014-04-01  20  
--  1   2014-05-01  20  
--  1   2014-06-01  20  
--  1   2014-07-01  20  
--  1   2014-08-01  20  
--  1   2014-09-01  20  
--  1   2014-10-01  20  
--  1   2014-11-01  20  
--  1   2014-12-01  20  
--  2   2013-01-01  32
--  2   2013-02-01  32
--  2   2013-03-01  32
--  2   2013-04-01  32
--  2   2013-05-01  32
--  2   2013-06-01  32
--  2   2013-07-01  32
--  2   2013-08-01  32
--  2   2013-09-01  32
--  2   2013-10-01  32
--  2   2013-11-01  32
--  2   2013-12-01  32
--  2   2014-01-01  32
--  2   2014-02-01  32
--  2   2014-03-01  32
```

Comment: Please provide desired output.

Comment: Nearest month is in terms greater or lesser or which has the priority?

Comment: I've never used loops in SQL - but I bet the solution to this involves a loop, a variable an a case statement.

Comment: Maheswaran Ravisankar: its less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the answer:**

```
Select    A.ID 
    , A.Date
    , (     Select Top 1 
                B.Hours
            From _Lookup B
            Where A.Date >= B.Date
                and A.Id = B.ID
            Order by B.Date desc
        ) as WorkingHours
From [_Basetable] A
```

Thanks for helping me out!!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
WITH MyTimeDate ([Year], [Month], Hours_Work) AS
(
    SELECT 2013,    1,  8   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    2,  16  UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    4,  8   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    5,  32  UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    9,  12  UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    10, 20  UNION ALL
    SELECT 2015,    1,  12 
)
,MySampleCal ([Year], [Month]) AS
(
    SELECT 2013,    1   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    2   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    3   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    4   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    5   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    6   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    7   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    8   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    9   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    10  UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    11  UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013,    12  
)
,DistanceCTE AS
(
    SELECT   C.[Year]
            ,C.[Month]
            ,D.Hours_Work
            ,DistanceSeq    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.[Year], C.[Month] ORDER BY D.[Month] - C.[Month] DESC)
    FROM MySampleCal    C
    JOIN MyTimeDate     D   ON  C.[Year] = D.[Year] 
                            AND C.[Month] >= D.Month 
)
SELECT *
FROM DistanceCTE
WHERE DistanceSeq = 1
```

Comment: Thanks MarkD, it looks like its close to my solution but i did not work for my SQL-code. I have added an extended example. Hopefully this will clear things out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've added a mysql tag to your question. I was unaware that it was a mysql problem, sorry I just assumed SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

From the very brief description of your issue Im able to help with following

If you have any ID on both of tables that is the same you can do

```
SELECT b.Jaar, b.Maand, a.Jaar, a.Maand ,a.Hours_Work,ISNULL(SUM(b.Hours_Work),0) FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON a.Key = b.Key
```

Or to join according to `Year` and `month`

```
SELECT b.Jaar, b.Maand, a.Jaar, a.Maand FROM s LEFT JOIN
a ON a.Hours_Work = b.Hours_Work and a.Jaar = b.Jaar and a.Maand = b.Month
```

Hope it helps.

If not, please describe.

Comment: Problem is table1 has gaps which i cant edit.. So it has to be some sort of range join. (closest to..)

Comment: Sorry, this is not working for me. I cant join table 1 because for some people it has only 1 record (data). It has to refer to table 1.

Comment: Thanks Marek. I have tried your solution but did not got the desired result... I have added an extended example so maybe this will clear things out. Thanks in advance!